# How to configure networking for two virtual machines on Virtualbox

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I am launching two virtual machines on virtualbox.

I want my virtual machines to have one interface for public access exactly like my host machine (blue link) and another interface for the internal network to connect virtual machines together.

What is the best way to do that with the highest performance possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable 2 network adapters on each VM and configure one of those adapters to the mode "internal networking", and set the other to the mode "host-only" or "bridged". (Do this on each VM, and ensure that they use the same internal network name).

Read more about it here: [Virtualbox networking](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html)